# Bluetooth multipoint changing source although source is silenced

Tags: fedora, bluetooth, pipewire

Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with the audio + bluetooth stack in Fedora and therefore lack the approach where to even look.

I connected my headset (Jabra Evolve 65) to both my laptop (Fedora 37) and my smartphone (Android device). When I am in a call with the smartphone and the headset and receive a system notification on the laptop, the call is put on hold and I hear the system notification. This is kind of desired in this way.
What is undesirable is that when I mute the sound output in Gnome, the behaviour remains the same: So a system notification leads to a change of the Bluetooth device, although there is no sound output. Does anyone have an idea how to describe this problem better and maybe even open a bug (pipewire? bluetoothd? gnome shell?).

Comment: So you paired your laptop using Bluetooth?

Comment: exactly. Paired with Bluetooth as "Headset Head Unit" with different Codecs depending on usage